# Library API exposure (and package protection) in Scala

Tags: scala, jvm

I am currently reading "Scala Programming, 2nd ed." (OReilly 2015) by Wampler/Payne, and they mention Package Objects as a means to expose abstractions.

On p.504 however, they mention

> *Package objects*
>   An alternative to finegrained visibility controls is putting all implementation constructs in a protected package, then using a top-level package object to expose only the appropriate public abstractions. For example, type members can alias types that would otherwise be hidden [...]"

Now my question is: is there a way to declare said *protected package* as protected once, without having to declare it for every every class/object down the hierarchy? And if so, how?
Or did I simply misunderstand the authors?

As clarification: I am currently working on a library which is supposed to expose minimal API in order for $colleagues to have to actually touch internals to make fundamental changes or to have to do configuration via config-files.
Second question: is this the right path to go? Should I maybe go another route?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little research of my own, it seems to me that it's not possible in Scala to declare a package to be entirely private. (You can check out the Language Specification [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), where there is no mention of being able to qualify a package declaration with 'private' or similar)

I think what the authors are suggesting is the following, roughly translated:

> Instead of using finegrained controls, such as declaring *some* of your class members private or protected and leaving the rest public, you could make all of the important classes in your package completely private (as in `private class/trait/object P {...}`). Then, you can put the important public details of the API into the package object, exposing these private innards. For example, if you need to expose a protected type, you can use type aliasing for that...